# Issue of scope, referencing iterator "i" from one for loop in another for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, scope, iterator

## Problem

I'm running into what I believe is an issue of scope with these two `for loops`. They are each iterating over a different number of items.

- **I'm trying to figure out how to reference the `i` iterator from the first loop in the second loop.**
- Specifically, I'm concatenating a string in the else portion of the if-statement in the second loop and I need to be able to reference both `i` and `j`

#### Clarification

*I'm trying to create a 11 x 8 grid totalling 88 squares. They need to have a specific class attached to them, which will color the squares. Each square has a data-id from 1 through 88 that determines their placement on the grid. The states / squares that need to be colored based on the data are not sequential as seen in the `data.json` snippet.*

### Loop #1

*i starts at 0, 1, 2 ... 50*

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {}
```

### Loop #2

*j starts at 1, 2, 3 ... 88*

```
for (j = 1; j < squaresTotal + 1; j++) {

    // If it doesn't exist, push those values into the an array
    if (states.indexOf(j) === -1){
        blanks.push(j);

        $("<div class='square is-white' data-id='" + j + "'></div>").appendTo(".map");
    } else {
        $("<div class='square " + data[i].class + "' data-id='" + j + "'><p class='square__state'>" + data[i].abbr + "</p></div>").appendTo(".map");
    }
}
```

#### scripts.js

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.json',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(main);
        });

        function main(data) {

            // The parent container that holds the map
            let map = $(".map");

            // IDs of the states and the blank tiles
            let blanks = [];
            let states = [];

            // Contains data for all 50 states
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                // Data is sorted by the rank field in descending order
                data.sort(function(a, b){
                    return a['rank'] - b['rank'];
                });

                // Fields for the data table below the map
                // Numbered rank (i.e. 1, 2, 3)
                let rank = data[i].rank;

                // Full state name (i.e. Alaska)
                let state = data[i].state;

                // Total consumer electric power
                let value = (data[i].total_consumption_electric_power).toLocaleString();

                // Each row in the table contains a rank, state and value
                if (rank) {
                    $("<tr><th scope='row'>" + data[i].rank + "</th><td>" + data[i].state + "</td><td>" + value + "</td></tr>").appendTo("tbody");
                }

                // Push the ids to the empty states array
                states.push(data[i].id);
            }

            // The grid is 11 by 8 for a total of 88 squares
            const squaresTotal = 88;

            for (j = 1; j < squaresTotal + 1; j++) {

                // If it doesn't exist, push those values into the an array
                if (states.indexOf(j) === -1){
                    blanks.push(j);

                    $("<div class='square is-white' data-id='" + j + "'></div>").appendTo(".map");
                } else {
                    $("<div class='square " + data[i].class + "' data-id='" + j + "'><p class='square__state'>" + data[i].abbr + "</p></div>").appendTo(".map");
                }
            }

            var pymChild = new pym.Child();
            pymChild.sendHeight();
        }


    </script>
```

### data.json (Snippet)

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "state": "Alaska",
    "rank": "",
    "abbr": "AK",
    "class": "square-1",
    "total_consumption_electric_power": 707913
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "state": "Maine",
    "rank": "",
    "abbr": "ME",
    "class": "square-1",
    "total_consumption_electric_power": 62360
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "state": "Wisconsin",
    "rank": "",
    "abbr": "WI",
    "class": "square-5",
    "total_consumption_electric_power": 19482575
  }
]
```

Comment: You could declare i outside of the first loop, but then it would always reference the same index in your second. Is that how you want it to work?

Comment: Place the for-loop of `j` inside the for-loop of `i`....  PS: appending new nodes inside a loop will trash your framerate once `i` and `j` are big enough. Prefer a documentFragment and do one append to the live page at the end.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen That's the only way you'll get 50 * 88 executions. Else, as stated before, `i` will always be 50 once the `j` loop runs. Why is `j` loop inside `i` loop not an option?

Comment: @daddygames If I reference `i` outside of the first loop, will it be able to count from `0, 1, 2 ... 50` while also ensuring that the `j` in the second loop counts from `1, 2, 3 ... 88`

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do, this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Please clarify what the intent is? And could you show a sample of  `data.json` ? The way I read the code is that there are 50 states, and you want to have 88 white squares for each state. If that is not correct, I don't understand what a line like `<div class='square " + data[i].class + "' data-id='" + j + "'>` is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in the intent. I'm trying to create a grid of 88 squares. They need to have a specific class attached to them, which will color the squares. Each square has a data-id from 1 through 88. The states that need to be colored based on the data are not sequential.

Comment: I understand now. You don't need `i` inside the `j` loop, since you only have 88 squares. Of those 88 squares, 50 will be a state and 38 will be blanks. Instead of `states.push(data[i].id);`, use `states.push({ id: data[i].id, class: data[i].class, abbr: data[i].abbr);`. Now you no longer need `i` inside the `j` loop if you change `if (states.indexOf(j) === -1){ blanks.push(j);`, since the class and abbr can also be inside `states[j].class` and such if you change the structure.

Comment: @Shilly Could a explain a little bit more with a code snippet how your proposed solution works?

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified some of the code to show how I would try to structure the code.

If you want to use JQuery to do the rendering, it's easily converted back.

This does not answer your index `i`, index `j` question, because you actually do not need those to do this in a way that seems simpler to me personally.

```js
var states = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "state": "Alaska",
    "rank": 2,
    "abbr": "AK",
    "class": "square-1",
    "total_consumption_electric_power": 707913
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "state": "Maine",
    "rank": 3,
    "abbr": "ME",
    "class": "square-1",
    "total_consumption_electric_power": 62360
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "state": "Wisconsin",
    "rank": 1,
    "abbr": "WI",
    "class": "square-5",
    "total_consumption_electric_power": 19482575
  }
];

var render_rankings_table = function( states ) {
  // We want the table to be sorted by rank.
  // By creating a new array from the passed states array,
  // we retain the original order inside the states array.
  var sorted_by_rank = states.sort((a, b ) => a.rank - b.rank );
  // Create a row for each sorted_by_rank state.
  // Since this is a new array, we can just loop over it without affecting the original states array.
  var rows_html = sorted_by_rank.map( state => {
    return `<tr><td scope="row">${ state.rank }</td><td>${ state.state }</td><td>${ state.total_consumption_electric_power }</td></tr>`;
  });
  // Overwrite the content of the table to render it.
  // See how we update the table only once at the end instead of for every state individually.
  var table = document.querySelector( '#electric_consumption_ranking' );
  table.innerHTML = rows_html.join( '' );
};

// The original contains: if (states.indexOf(j) === -1){ blanks.push(j); }
// The states array contained all the id's.
// So translated, this means that the id of the state, equals the square it will render to.
// So Maine, with id 11, will be the eleventh square.
var render_squares = function( states ) {
  // Creating the 88 squares and mapping the states to it can be done in multiple ways.
  // I would prefer the 'easy' solution of just creating an array with 88 elements and
  // then putting the states in the correct position,
  // instead of figuring out the position of the state inside the loop.
  var squares = Array.from({ length: 88 }).fill( false );
  // We now have an array cotnaining 'false' 88 times.
  // Now lets add the states to it.
  // The squares start at 1, the array index starts at 0, so subtract 1 from the id to get the correct index.
  states.forEach( state => { squares[ state.id - 1 ] = state; });
  // Now all the states are in the correct position, according to their id.
  // Create the squares.
  var squares_html = squares.map(( state, index ) => {
    if ( state ) {
      return `<div class="square ${ state.class }" data-id="${ index + 1 }"><p class="square__state">${ state.abbr }</p></div>`;
    
    }
    // The data-ids start at 1, the array index starts at 0, so add 1 to the index.
    // The <div> has to have height to actually show up on the screen.
    // The easiest way is to make sure the div contains text, so adding a space already works.
    // We could also give the divs a minimum height with CSS.
    else {
      return `<div class='square is-white' data-id="${ index + 1 }">&nbsp;</div>`;
    }
  });
  // Overwrite the map.
  var map = document.querySelector( '.map' );
  map.innerHTML = squares_html.join( '' );
};

render_rankings_table( states );
render_squares( states );
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.square {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

.map {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.is-white {
  background-color: rgb( 238, 238, 238 );
}
.square-1 {
  background-color: red;  
}
.square-5 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="electric_consumption_ranking"></table>
<figure class="map"></figure>
```

Comment: This is an amazingly thorough answer. Checking it over now, thanks for taking the time, and also to add comments.